# Screen scraping a mainframe screen in java?

Tags: java, screen-scraping, mainframe

I am new to programming world, and in my project I need to screen scrape a mainframe screen using attachmate? Can anyone tell me what exactly screen scraping is and how does it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the righthand column, the following link seems to answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302484/screen-scraping-a-mainframe-screen-in-c-without-3rd-party-utilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM used to offer a package that would allow TN3270 connections from straight Java.  I can't remember the name of the package, but if you can find that, you wouldn't need Attachmate at all.

Comment: For anyone looking for the software its called IBM HATS (Host Access Transformation Services) Toolkit . http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/hats/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to make a macro or module with Visual Basic for Attachemate's Reflecitons product.  Have your VB macro save the data somewhere and then your Java program can read it.